# Install xplanet version 0.95a on a modern Linux or update code to xplanet 1.3

Tags: compilation, tcl

I have an old `tcl` script, that I used to generate planets, but it needs to run with `xplanet` version 0.95a, because `xplanet` v1 is a complete rewrite and don't work with all the options I used.

The old version is still available [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xplanet/files/xplanet/) but how do I install it on Ubuntu 20.04?

Or would it be easy to convert the tcl script, so it will run on v1.3?

```
#! /usr/bin/wish

# create the file planet_conf with
# echo "1">planet_conf
#
# create maps from png with
# convert foo.ppm -compress none color_maps/colormap{0-27}.ppm

set fileid [open planet_conf r]
    set numb [read $fileid]
close $fileid

while {$numb < 10000} {
    set numb [expr {$numb +1}]
    set mixer [expr {0.1+(rand()*0.3)}]
    set crater [expr {int(rand()*3)}]
    set fade_number [expr {10+ int(rand()*7)}]  
    set randmap [expr {int(rand()*28)}]
    set randmap_crat [expr {int(rand()*28)}] 
    set randmap_atmos [expr {int(rand()*28)}]
    set dimensiona [expr {(rand()*3.1)}]
    set modus [expr {int(rand()*7)}]
    set dim [expr {0.5+$dimensiona}]
    set pow [expr {0.5+(rand()*1)}]
    set dim_atmos [expr {0.3+$dimensiona}]
        set pow_atmos [expr {0.3+(rand()*1)}]
    set degree [expr {96+(int(rand()*50))}]
    set invert [expr {(rand()*1)}]
    set size [expr {0.06+(rand()*0.15)}]
    puts $numb 
    puts "atmosphere map..."
    catch { exec  ppmforge -clouds -power $pow_atmos -width 600 -height 300 -mesh 1024 -dimension $dim_atmos > atmos.ppm } result
    catch {exec pnmremap -map=./color_maps/colormap$randmap_atmos.ppm atmos.ppm > atmos_remap.ppm} result
    catch { exec pnmsmooth -size 9 9 atmos_remap.ppm > atmos_cut.ppm } result
    catch { exec pnmcut atmos_cut.ppm -left 30 -right 286 -top 30 -bottom 286 > ./images/atmos_day_vorlage.ppm } result
    catch { exec pnmcut atmos_cut.ppm -left 287 -right 542 -top 30 -bottom 286 > atmos_dark.ppm } result
    catch { exec ppmbrighten -v -60 atmos_dark.ppm > ./images/atmos_night_vorlage.ppm } result
    puts "premapping..."
    if { $crater == 1 } {
        puts "crater"
        catch { exec pgmcrater -height 300 -width 600 > crater.pgm } result
        catch { exec pgmtoppm -map color_maps/colormap$randmap_crat.ppm  crater.pgm > crater.ppm  } result 
        puts $result    
        catch { exec  ppmforge -clouds -power $pow -width 600 -height 300 -mesh 1024 -dimension $dim > test.ppm } result
        puts $result
        if { $modus == 1} {
            catch { exec /usr/bin/ppmfade -f test.ppm -l crater.ppm -shift } result
        } elseif { $modus == 5} {
            catch { exec /usr/bin/ppmfade -f test.ppm -l crater.ppm -mix } result
        } elseif { $modus == 2} { 
            catch { exec /usr/bin/ppmfade -f test.ppm -l crater.ppm -spread } result
        } elseif { $modus == 3} { 
            catch { exec /usr/bin/ppmfade -f test.ppm -l crater.ppm -edge } result
        } elseif { $modus == 4} {
            catch { exec /usr/bin/ppmfade -f test.ppm -l crater.ppm -bentley } result
        } else {
            catch { exec /usr/bin/ppmfade -f test.ppm -l crater.ppm -relief } result
        }
        puts $result
        catch { exec cp fade.00$fade_number.ppm test.ppm } result
        puts $result
    } else {
         catch { exec  /usr/bin/ppmforge -clouds -power $pow -width 600 -height 300 -mesh 1024 -dimension $dim > test.ppm } result
    }
    puts $result
    puts "smoothing..."
    catch { exec pnmsmooth -size 5 5 test.ppm > test_smooth.ppm } result
    puts $result
    catch {exec pnmremap -map=./color_maps/colormap$randmap.ppm test_smooth.ppm > test_remap.ppm } result
    if { $invert < 0.5 } {
        puts "inverted"
        catch { exec pnminvert test_remap.ppm > test_middle.ppm } result
    } else {
        catch { exec cp test_remap.ppm test_middle.ppm } result
    }
    catch { exec pnmcut test_middle.ppm -left 30 -right 286 -top 30 -bottom 286 > ./images/vorlage_day.ppm } result
    catch { exec pnmcut test_remap.ppm -left 287 -right 542 -top 30 -bottom 286 > test_dark.ppm } result
    catch { exec ppmbrighten -v -70 test_dark.ppm > ./images/vorlage_night.ppm } result
    puts $result
    puts "planet generating ..."
    catch {exec xplanet -starfreq 0 -date "24 Jun 1999 11:02:17" -image vorlage_day.ppm -night_image vorlage_night.ppm -blend -radius 40 -output planet.ppm } result
    if {$result == ""} {
        puts "ok"
    } else {
        puts $result
    }
     catch {exec xplanet -starfreq 0 -date "24 Jun 1999 11:02:17" -image atmos_vorlage.ppm -night_image atmos_night_vorlage.ppm -blend -radius 41 -output atmos_ready.ppm } result
        if {$result == ""} {
            puts "ok"
        } else {
            puts $result
        }
    catch { exec ppmmix $mixer planet.ppm atmos_ready.ppm > complete.ppm } result 
    puts "scaling"  
    catch { exec pnmscale $size complete.ppm > planet_s1.ppm } result
    catch { exec ppmtojpeg planet_s1.ppm > planet_s1_$numb.jpg } result

    puts "" 
    set fileid [open planet_conf w]
        puts $fileid $numb
    close $fileid
    after 10 exec sleep 4
    #catch {exec display test$numb.jpg } result
}
```

Comment: "would it be easy to convert the tcl script, so it will run on v1.3?" -- that sounds like a question you should answer yourself. Have you done the research about what changed between the old version and the current version? Since you only call out to xplanet in 2 places, it should be straightforward to edit your script to account for the changed options.

Comment: Yes I researched, and I didn't find a hint about what happened to the -image option at all. Maybe it behaves like `night_image`? Described here a bit: http://xplanet.sourceforge.net/NEWS

Comment: Did you miss seeing http://xplanet.sourceforge.net/README.config ?

Comment: It looks to me (from that NEWS file) like the only definitely unsupported option is `-blend`; anything else is not obvious right now (but I've not read anything in depth). I've no idea whether that matters. The best option is probably to _just try it,_ read the error messages, and see what actually needs fixing. Maybe initially just make small images to speed up testing? Nothing about the Tcl code itself seems to need fixing (there are bits that could be more efficient, but that's tuning, not fixing…)

Comment: Speaking of tuning, this one really bugs me for some reason. `after 10 exec sleep 4` -> `after 4010`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to convert it to `xplanet` v1.3:

#### 1.

I had to create two config files, I use for the two `xplanet` calls:

`configs/xplanet_night.conf`:

```
[default]
min_radius_for_label=1000
[mars]
map=temp/atmos_vorlage.ppm
night_map=temp/atmos_night_vorlage.ppm
```

and `configs/xplanet_day.conf`

```
[default]
min_radius_for_label=1000
[mars]
map=temp/vorlage_day.ppm
night_map=temp/vorlage_night.ppm
```

#### 2.

Then i adapted the script so it looks like this:
https://github.com/rubo77/spacetrace-planet-generator

[image]